# How do I exclude files from karma code coverage report?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

Is there a way to exclude files from code coverage report for the karma coverage runner https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage  ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use several techniques here: karma uses [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) globs for file paths and use can take advantage of that to exclude some paths.

As first solution I'd say try to add only the paths of the file to preprocess with the coverage:

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      'src/**/*.js',
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],

    // coverage reporter generates the coverage
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    preprocessors: {
      // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
      // do not include tests or libraries
      // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
      'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },

    // optionally, configure the reporter
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    }
  });
};
```

The one above is the default example in karma-coverage and it shows that only those files in the `src` folder will be preprocessed.

Another trick can be to use the `!` operator to exclude specific paths:

```
preprocessors: {
  // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
  // do not include tests or libraries
  'src/**/!(*spec|*mock).js': ['coverage']
},
```

The one above makes the coverage run only on those Javascript files that do not end with `spec.js` or `mock.js`. The same can be done for folders:

```
preprocessors: {
  // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
  // do not include tests or libraries
  'src/**/!(spec|mock)/*.js': ['coverage']
},
```

Do not process any Javascript files in the `spec` or `mock` folder.

Comment: Tip: this will exclude all spec and mock folders, if they are in the src/spec and src/mock folders, then use like this: `'src/!(spec|mock)/**/*.js': ['coverage']`

Comment: Are you allowed to add multiple lines?  
  
`'src/**/*.js': ['coverage'],`
`'src/!(vendor)/*.js,*.js}': ['coverage']` . 
What I'm looking for is adding every .js file but excluding .js files that are part of vendor

Comment: Sure, you can add as many lines you want, as long each key/path are not duplicate.

Comment: @MarcoL i'm still getting vendor files in my lcov.info 

I've tried the above and this as well `'src/{**/!(vendor)/*.js,*.js}': ['coverage']`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `karma-esm` or `@open-wc/testing-karma`, which uses `karma-esm`, pass an Array of glob strings to `esm.coverageExclude`

```js
const { createDefaultConfig } = require('@open-wc/testing-karma');

const merge = require('deepmerge');

/**
 * @param  {import('@types/karma').Config} config
 * @return  {import('@types/karma').Config}
 */
module.exports = config => {
  config.set(merge(createDefaultConfig(config), {
    files: [{ pattern: config.grep ? config.grep : 'src/**/*.test.js', type: 'module' }],
    esm: {
      nodeResolve: true,
      babel: true,
      coverageExclude: ['src/*.test.js'],
    },
  }));
  return config;
};
```