# Angular 9 : Karma Coverage : How to display coverage report with only specific files

Tags: angular, code-coverage, istanbul, angular2-testing, karma-coverage

**Background**

We have an existing a huge angular application without any unit tests and we have just started writing the test cases. When I run the command

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

**Problem**

I see all the *.ts files in the report.
However, I just need the code coverage of 3 files for which I have created .spec files in my app and not all of them.

**What I tried**

After reading different stackoverflow posts it seems that there are some options `files` and `preprocessor` to be added in the tsconfig.json, and I could add my files like this:

```
  "files": [
    "src/app/products/details/activity/timeline.component.ts",
  ],
  "preprocessors": {
    "src/app/products/details/activity/timeline.component.ts": ["coverage"],
  },
```

**Question**

But this does not seem to work and I still see all the files in the coverage report.
How do I tell Angular/Karma/Istanbul to only show coverage of the files for only the files for which I wrote test cases.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help you: [How do I exclude files from karma code coverage report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135575/how-do-i-exclude-files-from-karma-code-coverage-report).

Basically you can exclude folders in the `preprocessor` using `!`.

```
preprocessors: {
  // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
  // do not include tests or libraries
  'src/**/!(spec|mock)/*.js': ['coverage']
},
```

Another way to exclude files of coverage is skip the actual test using the skip verbs for example in jasmine: `xdescribe xit` : [Jasmine](https://dtang.dev/2016-01-03-controlling-which-tests-run-in-jasmine/) or mocha `describe.skip`

Or just execute the only test that you want to know the coverage:

```
describe.only  -> mocha
fdescribe  -> jasmine
```

Just use this verbs in the file for the tests of the component:  `"src/app/products/details/activity/timeline.component.ts"`